# How to configure Jenkins to build projects automatically, if something was checked in with SVN?

Tags: java, maven, svn, jenkins

i have a question concerning Jenkins Buildserver und SVN. How can i configure my project job in jenkins in that way, that jenkins build automatically the project, if something was changed in the specific svn path of this project?

Thanks
Marwief

Comment: What have you tried exactly? This is pretty standard Jenkins behaviour - have you checked the manuals, e.g. [Configuring automatic builds](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-Configuringautomaticbuilds)

Comment: Do you meand the Pre-Steps or the ost-Steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the project configuration, there should be a **Build Triggers** section. This controls how often Jenkins polls your SCM for code changes.

When using SVN, you can afford to check quite frequently because the checking is not expensive. So you can tell Jenkins to check every minute or so. Set this to *Poll SCM* and set the schedule to something like `*/n * * * *` (replace `n` with your poll interval in minutes).

[image: build settings]

Full details can be found at this tutorial: [Your First Jenkins Build Job](http://jenkins-le-guide-complet.batmat.cloudbees.net/html/sect-first-steps-first-job.html).

Answer (score 0):

As I know, SVN files can be downloaded directly by HTTP, so you can set Jenkins to build automatically, when this file's changed: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/URL+Change+Trigger

Comment: but i need this kind of option only for one specific jenkins job and not as a global configuration for all available projects

Comment: This will be applied in one specific jenkins job, which you are configuring such a way.


Just install plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/URLTrigger+Plugin (yep, the one from the post is deprecated now), then configure your job to build when content of the URL in changed.